# onclick props not working with Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

here is my situation on React.js

I have a function on my App.js call selectNumberOfPeople,

then In my child component ( call General) I had a button as:

```
<button className="selectedNumberOfPeopleButton" onClick={this.selectedNumberOfPeople} value="1">
      1
</button>
```

which was displaying the value in the console on click.

Works perfectly.

I want to use a button from Material UI instead now, so I have replace my button with:

```
<RaisedButton className="selectedNumberOfPeopleButton" 
    onClick={this.props.selectedNumberOfPeople}
    value="1" 
    label="1" 
    labelPosition="before"
    primary={true}
/>
```

But the value doesnt display anymore int he console when using this . . .

though the function being in the parent component I do pass it by:

```
<General selectNumberOfPeople={this.selectNumberOfPeople} selectedPanel={this.showPanelAndHideOthers} />
```

and I tried to updated my child component ( General.js) like:

```
<RaisedButton selectNumberOfPeople={this.props.selectNumberOfPeople}
    className="selectedNumberOfPeopleButton" 
    onClick={this.props.selectedNumberOfPeople}
    value="1" 
    label="1" 
    labelPosition="before"
    primary={true}
/>
```

but it's still not working....

For your information,

the selectNumberOfPeople is in App.js as

```
selectNumberOfPeople(value) {
console.log('select number of people');
// update the state and provide a callback handler to be called after the state is updated.
// referencing the state before the call back function
// () => {
//   console.log(this.state.numberOfPeople)
// })
// will leave the state with the same value as before the setState function is called.
this.setState(
  {
    numberOfPeople: value,
  },
  () => {
    console.log(this.state.numberOfPeople);
  }
);
```

}

and in my general.js  (child component)

```
selectedNumberOfPeople(e) {
  this.props.selectNumberOfPeople(e.target.value);

  const list = document.getElementsByClassName('selectedNumberOfPeopleButton');
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].classList.remove('hover');
  }

  this.toggleSelectedButtonState(e);
}
```

Does anyone have any guidance in what I'm doing wrong ?

It will be super !!

Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.props.selectNumberOfPeople` not `selectedNumberOfPeople`.

```
 <RaisedButton
   className="selectedNumberOfPeopleButton" 
   onClick={this.props.selectNumberOfPeople}
   value="1" 
   label="1" 
   labelPosition="before"
   primary={true}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks NIshant, id does display somethign in the console now, but not the same as the previous button :( I'm looking to have the     numberOfPeople
 from     console.log(this.state.numberOfPeople); which i have added in the edit question . . . .  Many thanks for your time i really appreciate

Comment: Ok can you let me know what is coming inside `value` ?

Comment: value = "1" in this case but in the console i only get 'select number of people' instead of the value like i was having with the previous button.

see screenshot: https://snag.gy/Wn1jLa.jpg

Answer (score 0):

you can also try
     `onClick={()=>this.props.selectedNumberOfPeople}`

Comment: still no luck :(

WHen adding between '' I get this in the console

_this.props.onClick is not a function
    at EnhancedButton._this.handleClick

any idea ? I'm desesperate